# Modificar valor de textbox cuando select cambia

Tags: php, mysql

Poseo una tabla llamada **articulos**, esta tiene los siguientes campos:
**id_articulo** , **des_articulo** (descripción de lo citado en el articulo) y **articulo** (numero del articulo)

Tengo un formulario para registrar sanciones, donde uso esta tabla que contiene el articulo que la persona no respeto

Quisiera: que al cambiar las opciones del select, el textbox que esta aun lado cambie su valor por la **descripcion** siendo esta otro valor que esta en la misma tabla.

edite el codigo para que al cambiar el select mostrara el **ID** y en base a el, luego lo convierto usando el **SQL QUERY**. pero no se como hacer para que con cada cambio el se actualice

```
  <?php
include "conexion.php";
global $cone;
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align ="center">Bienvenido</h1>
<a href ="index.html"><ol>Pagina Principal</ol></a>
<a href ="registrar.php"><ol>Registrar</ol></a>
<a href ="listado.php"><ol>Listado</ol></a>
<a href ="Sancion.php"><ol>Sancion</ol></a>
<form method="POST" action ="procesar4.php">     
    <label> Ingrese cedula del sancionado</label>
    <input type="text" id="cedula" name="cedula1"><br/>

    <label> Ingrese cedula del sancionador</label>
    <input type="text" id="cedula" name="cedula2"><br/>

    <label> Ingrese tipo de sancion </label>
    <div><select name="sancion">
<?php
$registros=mysqli_query($cone,"select * from sanciones");
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){
echo "<option value='$reg[id_sancion]'>"."$reg[sancion]"."<br/>"."</option>";
}
?>
</select></div>
<label> Ingrese articulo inflingido </label>
<div><select name="articulo" id="articulo">
 <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Change es un evento que se ejecuta cada vez que se cambia el valor de un elemento (input, select, etc).
        $('#articulo').change(function(e) {

          $('#descripcion').val($(this).val());
        });
      });

</script>


<?php
$registros=mysqli_query($cone,"select * from articulos");
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){
echo "<option value='$reg[id_articulo]'>"."$reg[articulo]"."</option>";

}
$sql =mysqli_query($cone,"SELECT des_articulo 
FROM articulos 
WHERE id_articulo=id_articulo");
$sql2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
echo "<br/>"."<input type='text' id='descripcion' readonly value='$sql2[des_articulo]'>";

?>
</select></div>  


 <fieldset>
        <legend>Ingrese estado de sancion</legend>


<?php

global $cone;
$registros=mysqli_query($cone,"select * from estado_sanciones");
while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($registros)){
   echo "<label>";
   echo '<input type="radio" name="estado" value="'.$reg["estado_id"].'">'.$reg["estado"];
echo "</label>";
   }
?>
 </fieldset>
<br/>

<label> Ingrese Fecha inicial de la sancion</label>
  <div> 
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#fecha1" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>

<input type="text" name="fecha1" id="fecha1"></p>
 </div>

   <label> Ingrese Fecha Final de la sancion</label>
<div> 
    <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#fecha2" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
  <input type="text" name="fecha2" id="fecha2"></p>
 </div> 
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahí solo estás imprimiendo el *value* y no el *text* del *option*, cambia el value, en lugar de que el *value* del *option* sea el *id*, que sea el *contenido*, o puedes hacer lo siguiente para obtener el texto del *option* seleccionado

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Change es un evento que se ejecuta cada vez que se cambia el valor de un elemento (input, select, etc).
    $('#articulo').change(function(e) {

      $('#descripcion').val($('#articulo option:selected').text());
    });
  });
```

Comment: Trate la primera opcion y funciona bien, en el select te sale, las 3 definiciones del articulo, pero no es lo que quiero, quiero que la persona vea que articulo esta inflingiendo, por otro lado utilice la 2da forma y me copia en un lado es el mismo numero, quiero que sea algo asi:

https://k60.kn3.net/33E770DEF.png

Comment: Podrías explicarte mejor para poder ayudarte? Con lo que te di cambia la descripción a la descripción del articulo seleccionado en el select, además en la imagen tu tienes 3 select y 3 input, acá solo veo uno.
No entiendo que es exactamente lo que quieres.

Comment: sencillamente, el select de la izquierda muestra 101, 102, 103 los numeros de los aritculos, en la derecha que el textbox muestre que significan cada uno, eso esta en la base de datos.

101 = gritar
102 = llorar=

Answer (score 0):

Podrías directamente probar esto:

```
$('#descripcion').val($('#articulo').val());
```